# How to find extent of function inputs where all of its outputs are positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have  a **function**:  $\sin (10.99*x)$

How to find a min-max extent of x where all the function values are positive? 
 **Is brute-force the only solution?**

Is there also a possible solution if multiple sine functions of different periods are plotted at the same co-ordinate plane? The question would be, what is the extent of all the x's?

Comment: Could you do it if the $10.99$ was not there?  Note that $\sin$ alternates between positive and negative so there will be multiple regions where it is positive .

Comment: $\sin(x)$ is cyclic, but between $0$ and $2\pi$ ($x$ in radians), it's positive (including $0$) between $0$ and $\pi$. So for $\sin(a*x)$, that means $0\le x\le\pi/a$.

Comment: Thanks @JohnForkosh, Is there also a possible solution if multiple sine functions of different periods are plotted at the same co-ordinate plane? The question would be, what is the extent of all the x's?

Comment: Firstly, I noticed I made a mistake -- if $a\pi>2\pi$ then $a*x$ will perform more than one $2\pi$ cycle as $x$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$. And that clearly happens for your $a=10.99$. For that, we have several intervals $0\le x\le\pi/a$ as originally, and then $2\pi/a\le x\le 3\pi/a$, etc, until $n\pi$ with $n>a$. And now, if you're asking when all the functions, for several different $a$'s  are simultaneously positive, then I'm not offhand seeing a closed form for that (though it's probably 50-50 or better there is one). Personally I'd just "brute force" program it, for a million or less points.

Comment: @user547729: The point of badjohn's suggestion was not to get rid of 10.99 forever. The point is finding out where exactly your inability to tackle the mathemacial problem is. If you can solve the problem without the 10.99, then the answer needs to be different than if you can't solve it. The point of this site is (partially) to help people get better at math, not just to provide solutions.

Comment: Oh I couldn't think it that way and I'm sorry for my stupid comment. Deleted it right away! @badjohn and yeah I could do it without the 10.99.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnForkosh, I got it.

Comment: @Ingix You read my mind.

Comment: @user547729 It seems that you got it now but I would have suggested trying $\sin(2 x)$ next.  It will just scale your answer.  Whatever the stupid comment was, I didn't see it.

Comment: @badjohn. Could you show me an example? My previous comment was stupid in a way that I was going off on a tangent while you had shown me a parabola way. Precisely, I misunderstood what you wrote and gave my stupid opinion based upon that.

Comment: As I said, I didn't see  the comment but, of course, I am curious now.  My first comment was a hint to try to get you on your way; not a complete solution.  I'll post an answer.  I hope that it does not go too far the other way.

Comment: I'm happy that you didn't saw it.  :) Yeah, sometimes `other way` is way too long to walk. That's why there are brill people like you and stackexchange. Thanks for the answer @badjohn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's build up to an answer.  You will need some basic knowledge of the $\sin$ function.

You probably learned $\sin$ first in degrees: $\sin(0 ^\circ) = 0$, it grows to a maximum of $1$ at $90 ^\circ$, falls back to $0$ at $180 ^\circ$, goes negative and reaches $-1$ at $270 ^\circ$, comes back up to $0$ at $360 ^\circ$ and then repeats.

Serious maths usually uses radians rather than degrees.  So, that becomes: $\sin(0) = 0$, it grows to a maximum of $1$ at $\pi /2$, falls back to $0$ at $\pi$, goes negative and reaches $-1$ at $3 \pi / 4$, comes back up to $0$ at $2 \pi$ and then repeats.

So, in radians, it is positive in the range $(0, \pi)$ not inclusive.  It is also positive again in the range $(2 \pi, 3 \pi)$ and this repeats every $2 \pi$.

Now, let's look at $sin(2 x)$.  Can we deduce its behaviour from that of $sin(x)$.  Let's write $2x$ as $y$.  When is $\sin(y)$ positive?  Well, when $y$ is in the ranges $(0, \pi)$, $(2 \pi, 3 \pi)$, etc.  So, if $y$ is in the range $(0, \pi)$ what about $x$?  Well $x$ is just half of $y$ so $x$ must be in the ranges $(0, \pi / 2)$, $(\pi, 3 \pi / 2)$, etc.

What about your example?  Just do my last example again with $10.99$ in place of $2$.  The same except for messier arithmetic.